# Using vlookup to update from different workbooks on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a number of google sheets that I want to use to update a "master" version. Which is all of those sheets combined into one.
I'm trying to use VLookup and importrange so that I don't have to physically copy and paste the data from one workbook into the master workbook.

```
=VLOOKUP(A353, IMPORTRANGE("1OBjYxloyuCEqpcM_C3cDjNiHb2k1LN7hnthAbKoKhS0", "summary!I2:I132"), 9)
```

This is the formula that I've tried to use
This is the sheet I'm trying to copy from (sheet ID may be different because I made a copy for posting here) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yJxrH3fkYbZ1p0zpSHXH_58pjWwrjOEyj52zp_tjxw/edit#gid=0

And this is the master file I'm trying to update.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FaLQT_QX80R6cqiWRohcrP4n7Wh9QDT2s_orhDCL7Vc/edit#gid=0

Each sheet has permission to access the other but I get an error saying `Vlookup evaluates to an out of bounds range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only importing column I so the VLOOKUP won't find a match (in column A).

Try changing your formula to

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A353, IMPORTRANGE("1OBjYxloyuCEqpcM_C3cDjNiHb2k1LN7hnthAbKoKhS0", "summary!A2:I132"), 9))
```

and see if that works (assuming there is a value in column I for the nestbox ID from column A)

Note: If you need a VLOOKUP in all cells I would suggest to import the table once (in a new tab) and then do the vlookups using that new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, JPV that helped me figure it out.

For myself, I had to use the full URL in the range to get it to work. I also specified False on the VLookup.

I would try this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A353, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBjYxloyuCEqpcM_C3cDjNiHb2k1LN7hnthAbKoKhS0", "summary!A2:I132"),9, FALSE),"-")
```

Or this if you are constantly adjusting the range:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A353, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBjYxloyuCEqpcM_C3cDjNiHb2k1LN7hnthAbKoKhS0", "summary!A:I"),9, FALSE),"-")
```